Why does the Keras Embedding layer result in an "unbuilt" model in the summary?
In my model setup, despite specifying parameters for the Embedding layer, such as input dimension (input_dim), output dimension (output_dim), and input length (input_length), the summary output indicates that the Embedding layer is displayed as "unbuilt." This issue suggests that the layer may not be properly initialized or configured with the correct input shape information. What could be causing this issue, and how can it be resolved to ensure that the Embedding layer is correctly built and included in the model summary with the appropriate parameters?
Code:
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size,output_dim=500,input_length=(2917,)))
model.compile('adam')
model.summary()
I am working on amazon reviews dataset vocab size=138203 and input seq length=2917(after padding)
Result:
Model: "sequential_1" ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓ ┃ Layer (type)                    ┃ Output Shape           ┃       Param # ┃ ┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩ │ embedding_16 (Embedding)        │ ?                      │   0 (unbuilt) │ └─────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┴───────────────┘ Total params: 0 (0.00 B) Trainable params: 0 (0.00 B) Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)

In karas, sometimes models don’t fully initialize the layer parameters until they are explicitly built with an input shape. You can fix this by manually building the model with model.build(input_shape), specifying the expected shape of your input data.
Since you’re working with an Embedding, your input shape will be (batch_size, sequence_length). Here, batch_size is often set to None (indicating any batch size), and sequence_length should match the expected input length for your sequences (i.e., the number of tokens in each sequence).
Example Code Sample:
# Build the model explicitly with the input shape

model.build(input_shape=(None, sequence_length))

It is recommended to build the model before compiling it.
